# How Do I Call a Template from Within Another Template's Helper Function When Using Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I'm am trying to call one template from within another template but I'm getting this weird output?

```
<!--label:qK29F4s8LzAJET2td-->
```

Here is my first template that is calling the other template

```
<template name="messages_create">

    <form id="create_email" class="container-fluid">

        <input type="text" id="email_to" placeholder="Enter Recipient" value="{{contact.fullName}} <{{contact.email}}>" class="span12">

        <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" value="{{record.subject}}" class="span12">

        <textarea id="body" placeholder="Body" rows="4" class="span12">{{{template}}}</textarea>

     </form>

</template>
```

and here is the helper declaration

```
Template.messages_create.template = function () {
    return Template.welcome_email();
}
```

and the 2nd template

```
<template name="welcome_email">

    <p>Good Afternoon {{to}},</p>

    <p>{{to}}, Welcome to my site!</p>

</template>
```

I also tried calling the template directly from within the the other template without declearing a helper like `{{> welcome_email}}`

Comment: You need to understand how Meteor rendering works. When eventedmind.com comes back online watch the template series. Youll find out whats happening.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the template directly should have worked and the helper is not necessary.  I think the handlebars call is sensitive to extra spaces.  Try:

```
{{>welcome_email}}
```